# If y̅ and S are based on a random sample y1 , ⋯ , yn from Np (μ, Σ), then y̅ and S are independent. How do I prove the above statement?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Condition for independence: cov(X,Y) = 0.
But how do I apply this condition in the given scenario?

Comment: That is a consequence of independence not the definition.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512832/321264). Refer to standard textbooks on multivariate analysis.